# Step parameter for input type of range

Tags: html, input, range

Is it possible to specify a decimal for a step parameter within the range element? According to a few articles I've read, including one on [Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/rethinking-forms-in-html5/), this should be possible. This does not appear to be working in any browsers. I've tried Chrome, Safari, and mobile Safari. Am I misunderstanding simple here, or is this just not supported quite yet?

```
 <input id='something' type='range' min='0' max='20' step='.25' value='5' />
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Df57B/

Check out this demo it is possible to give steps in decimal.

```
<input type="range" name="points" min="1" max="10" 
       step="0.25" onchange="alert(this.value)"/>
```

Your mistake take is that you gave .25 instead of 0.25.

Answer (score 6):

The following works for me in chrome, I'm thinking that it's the shortcut `step=".25"` that won't work

```
 <input id="something" type="range" min="0" max="0" step ="0.25" value="5" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it work in Firefox 4+, you can use the following: [HTML5Slider](https://github.com/fryn/html5slider)