# How to make slider use decimal values

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I would like to display a slider with values from 0kg to 1kg, with pips every 100g, and the label should display 'g' and 'kg' respectively:

0 100g 200g 300g 400g 500g 600g 700g 800g 900g 1kg

1. How do I format the label depending on the value?
2. I want the slider to take 30g value for example, and have the thumb appear in the correct position. In the same time, if user drags the thumb, it should snap at 100g.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Step parameter for input type of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369252/step-parameter-for-input-type-of-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`noUiSlider` has a `step` property. Initialize like this:

```js
noUiSlider.create(container, {
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 1000,
    },
    step: 100,
    //.... your other items
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I format the label depending on the value?

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct for the trouble of replying, although you didn't really answer my question, I figure it out myself

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if noUiSlider has that option, but im sure it may make an interesting addition over at their github. I might make a PR and do that. Ill let you know if I do.

Comment: which option are you referring to?

Comment: Formatting the label depending on its value.

Comment: Then what is your question?